# Magento keeps going to install after migration

Tags: install, local.xml, migration

I have recently made a duplicate copy of a customers Magento installation and put it into a subdirectory of the root.  I did a dump of the database and imported it into a new database.  I changed the local.xml file to reflect the new database.  Now my issue comes when I try to view the site under the new subdirectory to keeps invoking the install as if the local.xml file is missing.  It is clearly there in the app/etc folder within the cloned site, but still the install keeps starting.  Any ideas?  Below I have pasted the connection info in the local.xml file, just in case I miss typed something.

```
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[stevenst_newUser]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[bmalldo]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[stevenst_storeupgrade]]></dbname>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

Comment: Did you update the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` values in the database? Have a look in the `core_cofig_data` table and update those values to reflect the new setup.

Comment: also make sure if you are suing any table prefix or not if yes then also you need to mention this in local,xml

Comment: Make sure your local.XML file has the correct file permission.

Comment: Yes I updater the url in the database and I am not using any prefixes.  Matter of fact I just copied the local.xml from the working site and just changed the database name.

Comment: What is the file permission suppose to be?

Comment: Try to change the file permission that is readable by the current user or change the ownership.

Comment: Have you tried removing the local.xml you created and letting the install process create it for you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the file permissions on the following folders and it will work fine

```
chmod -R o+w var media app/etc
```

make sure your local.xml is set to 644